# SQL query in VBscript

Tags: vbscript

Can help me please in updating this sql query to be executed in an VBscript function, I have errors in the syntax.

I got "Expected end of statement" as error message.

```
sql4 = "SELECT MAX(price)  INTO maximun_price FROM table1  WHERE item_num = ("SELECT MAX(item_num) FROM table2 WHERE ITEM_TYPE IN ('T', 'R') AND seller_num = ("SELECT seller_num  FROM Sellers WHERE seller_code LIKE 'xyz'")");"
```

I need to update this query syntax to be accepted by VBcsript editor.

Comment: Your strings are broken.

Comment: What I mean is you can't have quotes embedded within your string because VBScript thinks you're ending the string.  Therefore, you have to escape them by using two in a row.  But you don't need to quote your sub-queries anyway (see my answer).

Comment: @sourh strings start and end with `"` in VBScript so at the moment they are broken.

Comment: Yeah, this solves my problem, thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your string to this:

```
sql4 = "SELECT MAX(price) INTO maximun_price FROM table1  WHERE item_num = (SELECT MAX(item_num) FROM table2 WHERE ITEM_TYPE IN ('T', 'R') AND seller_num = (SELECT seller_num  FROM Sellers WHERE seller_code LIKE 'xyz'));"
```

You don't need quotes in sub-queries, and even if you did, you'd have to escape them anyway so they wouldn't run afoul of the VBScript syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your string in VBScript is broken it should look more like this';

```
sql4 = "SELECT MAX(price)  INTO maximun_price FROM table1  WHERE item_num = (SELECT MAX(item_num) FROM table2 WHERE ITEM_TYPE IN ('T', 'R') AND seller_num = (SELECT seller_num  FROM Sellers WHERE seller_code LIKE 'xyz'));"
```

Not sure where the extra string quotes came from but they will cause a syntax error in VBScript. This is clearly highlighted in the code block in your question because the syntax highlighting for the string breaks at `item_num = ("`.